# Shell - Concatenate rows in Column1 If Column 2 has duplicates

Tags: shell, awk

I am a newbie for shell programming and currently facing a roadblock in arriving a solution,

I want to concatenate the column A values iff column B is same.

Here is the sample input,

```
Col A     Col B
AAA      www.google.com
BBB      www.google.com
CCC      www.gmail.com 
DDD      www.yahoo.com
```

Expected Output

```
Col A     Col B 
AAA,BBB  www.google.com
CCC      www.gmail.com
DDD      www.yahoo.com
```

I am using the below Awk command to segregate the duplicate entries,

```
awk 'NR == 1 {p=$2; next} p == $2 { printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$2} {p=$2}' FS="," Input.csv
```

But I am not able to get the duplicates segregated.

Any suggestions or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a Java tag?

Comment: Rookie mistake. Removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are not worried about the sequence of the output(like it should be same as shown Input_file) then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} {a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2] "," $1:$1}  END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}'  OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Col A     Col B
CCC     www.gmail.com
DDD     www.yahoo.com
AAA,BBB www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is generating the output in the expected format but discarding some items.

Comment: It seems the input has been pasted. Can you please check?

Comment: @ArunKumar, ahhh check now :) and let me know.

Comment: I am getting the response in the expected format but i am missing some data.

For Eg : If there are three www.google.com values then i am getting only two in the output

Comment: @ArunKumar, I am seeing same output as per shown sample,please be clear what is missing here??

Comment: My actual input file has 4 columns so the output was bit different for me earlier. Now i have fixed it locally. It works and thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info